# Parse and transform XML string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have simplified xml with only tags and no attributes no prolog and no namespaces where tags are colors like

```
<red>hello <blue>blue</blue> world</red>
```

and I need to transform it to a list:

```
<red>hello </red><blue>blue</blue><red> world</red>
```

actually I need:

```
[[;red;]hello ][[;blue;]blue][[;red;] world]
```

What is the simplest or best way to do this in JavaScript with help from jQuery?

Comment: @Andy I was thinking of use stack to hold tag name and using `string.split(/(<\/?[a-zA-Z]+>)/);` but maybe there is simple way using jQuery `$(string)` and `map` or `each`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've use stack based parse function using regex to split into tokens.

```js
function(string) {
    var stack = [];
    var output = [];
    var parts = string.split(/(<\/?[a-zA-Z]+>)/);
    for (var i=0; i<parts.length; ++i) {
        if (parts[i][0] == '<') {
            if (parts[i][1] == '/') {
                if (stack.length) {
                    stack.pop();
                }
            } else {
                // get name of the tag
                stack.push(parts[i].replace(/^<|>$/g, ''));
            }
        } else {
            if (stack.length) {
                // top of the stack
                output.push('[[;' + stack[stack.length-1] + ';]');
            }
            output.push(parts[i]);
            if (stack.length) {
                 output.push(']');
            }
        }
    }
    return output.join('');
}
```